# Join tables with non distinct values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this query which returns active users for our EBS system. Im trying to join this results with one more table in order to get theirs supervisor id but my problem is that i get cartesian product when trying to join with email address column of table EMPDATA_IMPORT. I need to use email column, because i do not have employee id populated for some users in fnd_user table.

```
SELECT 
  fu.user_name       "User name",  frt.responsibility_name "Responsibility Name" ,
  furg.start_date     "Start Date" ,  furg.end_date      "End Date" ,
  fu.last_logon_date    "Last Logon Date",  fr.responsibility_key  "Responsibility key",
  fu.email_address     "Email Address",  fu.description      "Description", x.supervisor_id
FROM
  fnd_user_resp_groups_direct   furg,  fnd_user        fu,
  applsys.fnd_responsibility_tl  frt,  applsys.fnd_responsibility   fr, EMPDATA_IMPORT  x
WHERE  furg.user_id = fu.user_id
  AND furg.responsibility_id = frt.responsibility_id
  AND fr.responsibility_id = frt.responsibility_id 
  AND (to_char(fu.END_DATE) is null  OR fu.END_DATE > sysdate)
   and fu.email_address=x.EMAIL_ADDRESS -- x has non distinct values for email address
```

Ok i will try to describe table data for EMPDATA_IMPORT :

```
Emp_id    Full_name supervisor_id     email_address              
 10       John Doe    100             jdoe@mm.com  
 10       John Doe    100             jdoe@mm.com 
 10       John Doe    100             jdoe@mm.com
100       Mike King   200             mking@mm.com
```

One other thing, by joining with email column above one i need to somehow present manager's name (using supervisor id) in above query. I cant figure it out....

How to manage this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the problem that `EMPDATA_IMPORT` has duplicate rows for the same user and email? Or that there are different users with the same email? Example data and expected results would help.

Comment: Please see question now, i have edit with more details. Thank you

Comment: Looks like `select DISTINCT ...` might do.

Comment: How exactly? I need to join with email_id those 2 queries and get supervisor name for each account in first query